# Convergence in mean implies $\sup\mathbb{E}[|X - X_n|^p] < \infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables converging in $L^p$ to a random variable X.

Does this fact implies that $\sup\mathbb{E}|X - X_n|^p < \infty $?

I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_n \to X$ in $L^{p}$ means $E|X_n-X|^{p} \to 0$. Any convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded so $(E|X_n-X|^{p})$ is bounded.

Comment: So $\sup \mathbb{E}|X_n|^p$ is also bounded for $p \geq 1$ because 
$$ \sup (\mathbb{E}|X|^p)^{1/p} \leq \sup [(\mathbb{E}|X_n - X|^p)^{1/p} + (\mathbb{E}|X|^p)^{1/p}]~?$$